# How do I query Exchange EWS with Postman?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Postman, how does one query the **On-Premise Exchange 2016 EWS**?

I have my organizations URL for EWS `https://my.organization.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx`. We're using Exchange 2016, no Office 365, Azure AD, or anything Azure. What I want to do is basically either `GET` or `POST` to issue a [simple query on users in our GAL (global address list) given a user principal name, first name, or last name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findpeople-operation).

The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) on this seems to be either vague, outdated, wrong, significantly lacking material, poorly worded, or oriented toward Office 365/Azure AD.

Any attempt so far yields a `401 Unauthorized` in Postman. I do not want to use the EWS Managed API because the final implementation will not be written in .NET but instead in Angular or NodeJS. **My machine is domain joined**. I've tried using [NTLM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange#ntlm-authentication) authentication with Postman already and I still get the `401 Unauthorized` response.

Again, I'm not looking for mailbox features (sending, receiving, display the mailbox, nor calendar, or anything of that nature), just searching the GAL with Postman and sending the appropriate SOAP envelopes with Postman.

Comment: Did it get resolved? for me as well, it works with managed API, but via postman. I have basic auth enabled and using postman's basic auth mechanism